# Dual NICS in one PC

Tags: network-adapter

Running Windows 10, we currently have a NIC card inside our computer that is used to connect directly to a special printer we have.  It uses the printers subnet, ip, etc.

Because of this, we are unable to ALSO connect to the internet.

We want to install a second NIC card, so we can connect to our routers subnet, gateway, etc.

Is this as simple as installing a second NIC card and just configuring it for our router, and the other NIC will just work as previously?

Comment: Generally, yes. There are many servers which have 6 or more NICs and all work fine. It's hard to say for sure without knowing more about the networks you are connecting to.